How to trigger a lambda function multiple times but only trigger the alarm in the final iteration
I want to trigger an AWS lambda function for multiple times and make it trigger an alarm only if the output of last iteration matches the metric filter. The lambda runs linux commands on an ec2 linux instance to remove and verify if files are deleted from particular directory and return output as "Failed" in Aws log groups. Metric filter is also set as Failed. I am running it with 850 second sleep to let the commands execute and 15 minute timeout but it still causes below error :
[ERROR] IndexError: list index out of range Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 39, in lambda_handler     last_output_outbound = output_valori_tosplit[2]
On next run it usually turns into OK state.
import json, boto3, time

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('ssm')

    instance_id = 'i-'  # Replace with the actual instance ID

    response = client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id],
        DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
        Parameters={
            'commands': [
                'find /mnt1/lean-batch/bift-outbound/done -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | wc -l',  #outbound 1 year for all files 
                'find /mnt1/lean-batch/bift-outbound/done -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;',
            
                'find /mnt1/lean-batch/bift-outbound/done -maxdepth 1 -mtime +180 -type f -name "VeiPda.*" -exec ls -l {} \; | wc -l',  #180 days for VeiPda 
                'find /mnt1/lean-batch/bift-outbound/done -maxdepth 1 -mtime +180 -type f -name "VeiPda.*" -exec rm -f {} \;',
               
                'find /mnt1/lean-batch/bift-outbound/done -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | wc -l',
                'find /mnt1/lean-batch/bift-outbound/done -maxdepth 1 -mtime +180 -type f -name "VeiPda.*" -exec ls -l {} \; | wc -l'
            ]
        }
    )

    command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']

    time.sleep(850)

    output = client.get_command_invocation(
        CommandId=command_id,
        InstanceId=instance_id,
    )

    output_valori = output['StandardOutputContent']
    output_valori_tosplit = output_valori.split()
    print(output_valori_tosplit)
 
    last_output_outbound = output_valori_tosplit[2]
    last_output_VEIpda = output_valori_tosplit[3]

    if int(last_output_outbound or last_output_VEIpda) > 10:
        Esito = "Failed"
        obj = {
            "Esito": Esito,
            "Failed_Log": output_valori,
        }
        print(json.dumps(obj))
        return obj
    else:
        Esito = "OK"
        obj = {
            "Esito": Esito,
            "OK_Log": output_valori,
        }
        print(json.dumps(obj))
        return obj


The error is saying that output_valori_tosplit does not contain 3 elements. Don't forget that Python starts counting at zero! Or, perhaps you meant to use output_valori_tosplit.split()[2]?

Hi John, I have updated my question with lambda code. Lambda works properly without any error but sometimes it still throws that list index out of range error. On next run it is usually OK. My question was how do I make alarm trigger multiple times but make it so that metric filter will trigger on last ouput. For example, i run this lambda 5 times, there will be 5 outputs in log groups but the alarm should trigger only if 5th output is Failed in log group. Any better approach is also appreciated. Thanks.
